# How to use crypto++ Blowfish correctly

Tags: c++, binary, blowfish, crypto++

I have been trying all day today to finde out how to read from a binary file and decrypt it.

In my file, the first 4 bytes is describing the file format, the 32 bytes after it is the header, which is encrypted with Blowfish.

so i wrote this code to be able to do this:

```
string file = "C:\\test.bin";    

byte *header = new byte[32];

FILE *data = fopen(file.c_str(), "r");

if(data == NULL)
{
    return 1; //Error opening file!
}

char type[6];

type[5] = 0;

if(fread(type, sizeof(type) - 1, 1, data) < 1)
{
    return 2;
}

if(strcmp(type, "ABCD") != 0)
{
    return 3;
}

if(fread(header, sizeof(header), 1, data) < 1)
{
    return 2; //Error reading file!
}

vector<byte> key;

key.push_back(0xAA);
key.push_back(0xBB);
key.push_back(0xCC);
key.push_back(0xDD);
key.push_back(0xAA);
key.push_back(0xBB);
key.push_back(0xCC);
key.push_back(0xDD);

ECB_Mode<Blowfish>::Decryption decryption(key.data(), key.size());

byte out[32];

decryption.ProcessData(out, header, 32);

FILE *outer =  fopen("C:\\out.bin", "w");

fwrite (out, sizeof(byte), sizeof(out), outer);
```

but this is not decrypting the data correctly.

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Please make your code self-contained when posting on SO: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfb51ef2402b3d80 (69 lines of code, my answer replaces it with 39 lines of code (actually, less, beause my code does more)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to loop over Blowfish Crypto++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300694/how-to-loop-over-blowfish-crypto)

Comment: `ECB_Mode` is probably a bad choice. Choose a mode like `EAX`, `GCM` or `CCM`. `ECB` mode is only secure for one block of cipher text. Anymore than one block, the mode leaks information. In your code, you should see repeats in the cipher text of `C:\test.bin`. The repeats will occur on 8-byte boundaries.

Comment: I'm sorry, i almost forgot it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's many things a bit smelly here

- `fopen` should use `"rb"` and `"wb"` for binary mode
- you should use `memcmp` instead of `strcmp`
- you don't validate that `fread` actually read 4 bytes
- you should prefer `unsigned char` for binary data (fewer pitfalls to do with sign extension and undefined behaviour on overflow)
- if you're using C++, why use cstdlib, cstdio and cstring in the first place?
- this is a **bug**

  ```
  if(fread(header, sizeof(header), 1, data) < 1)
  ```

  `sizeof (header)` is `sizeof(byte*)` here, not `32` as you seem to expect

Here's a quick review of the code in c++ style: **Update** added a length field for my real-life roundtrip test (see below).

`decryptor.cpp`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <crypto++/blowfish.h>
#include <crypto++/modes.h>

static std::vector<byte> const key { 's','e','c','r','e','t' };
static byte const SIGNATURE[] = "ABCD"; //{ 'A','B','C','D' };

int main()
{
    if (std::ifstream data {"test.bin", std::ios::binary})
    {
        char type[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        if (!data.read(type, 4))
        {
            return 2;
        }

        auto mismatch = std::mismatch(std::begin(SIGNATURE), std::end(SIGNATURE), std::begin(type));

        if (mismatch.first != std::end(SIGNATURE))
        {
            return 3;
        }

        uint32_t length = 0;
        if (!data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&length), sizeof(length))) // TODO use portable byte-order
        {
            return 4;
        }

        std::vector<byte> const ciphertext { std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(data), {} };
        // to read 32 bytes: 
        // std::copy_n(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(data), 32, std::back_inserter(ciphertext));

        assert(data.good() || data.eof());
        assert(ciphertext.size() >= length);
        assert(ciphertext.size() % CryptoPP::Blowfish::BLOCKSIZE == 0);

        CryptoPP::ECB_Mode<CryptoPP::Blowfish>::Decryption decryption(key.data(), key.size());

        std::vector<char> plaintext(ciphertext.size());

        decryption.ProcessData(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(plaintext.data()), ciphertext.data(), plaintext.size());
        plaintext.resize(length); // trim padding

        std::ofstream out("out.bin", std::ios::binary);
        out.write(plaintext.data(), plaintext.size());
    } else
    {
        return 1; //Error opening file
    }
}
```

I don't have a file yet to test it with.

**Update** So, I've made **[an `encryptor.cpp`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/621b67959a1d4880)** now too.

```
echo "Hello world" | ./encryptor
```

results in a 40 byte file (sig + length + ciphertext = 4 + 4 + 32 = 40), in base64:

```
base64 test.bin
QUJDRAwAAABCaDMrpG0WEYePd7fI0wsHAQoNkUl1CjIBCg2RSXUKMg==
```

Now, decrypting that tests out fine. Note that I found that I needed to ensure padding was done to BLOCKSIZE, and as such I added a `length` field to store the actual size of the plaintext to avoid trailing garbage after decryption.

You can see the roundtrip by doing

```
echo 'Bye world!!' | ./encryptor && ./decryptor && cat out.bin
```

Which does indeed print the greeting back after decryption.

Note **specifically** the `TODO`'s. You should probably [use `StreamTransformationFilter` which adds padding as required.](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Blowfish)

Comment: Added fully tested roundtrip encryptor/decryptor. Some extra observations and link to CryptoPP `StreamTransformationFilter` were added in case you handle payloads != 32 bytes too.

Comment: @salim_aliya Of course it does, because I tested it for this very reason. I can take a stab: your compiler is too old to compile my code (or you don't supply `-std=c++11`). Or, you failed to notice my sample uses a different key, and allows for variable-length payloads.

Comment: Please can you explain what's ciphertext and for what it's needed? EDIT: I'm sorry, i havent refreshed the site ... :D

Comment: @salim The whole point here is that you can see what went wrong, what constitutes modern C++ code. We're not here to reimplement your program for you.

Comment: Ciphertext is just ... ciphertext. You called this variable `header`.