# 'message hash or MAC not valid' exception after decryption

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, crypto++

I'm trying to make a program that encrypts files (.jpg and .avi) using the crypto++ libraries. My aim is to make a program  that successfully encrypts video files using AES-256.

I did text examples of AES encryption from [here](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) and they ran successfully (meaning that the library is setup correctly). However, the following simple code produces the exception

```
HashVerificationFilter: message hash or MAC not valid
```

Code:

```
AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

SecByteBlock key(AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
prng.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());

SecByteBlock iv(AES::BLOCKSIZE);
prng.GenerateBlock(iv, iv.size());

string ofilename = "testimage.png";
string efilename;
string rfilename = "testimagerecovered.png";

try
{

    GCM< AES >::Encryption e;
    e.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, iv.size());

    ifstream ofile(ofilename.c_str(), ios::binary);
    ofile.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);

    FileSource fs1(ofilename.c_str(), true,
            new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(e,
                    new StringSink(efilename)));

    GCM< AES >::Decryption d2;
    d2.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, sizeof(iv));

    StringSource fs2(efilename, true,
            new AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter( d2,
                    new FileSink (rfilename.c_str()),
                    AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION));
}
catch(const Exception &e)
{
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    exit(1);
}

return 0;
```

I suspect I am not implementing the AES algorithm correctly. However, I am unable to find a solution for the last two days. I'm using Eclipse Luna on  Ubuntu 14.04.

PS I have gone through the following answers

[How to read an image to a string for encrypting Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354548/how-to-read-an-image-to-a-string-for-encrypting-crypto)

[How to loop over Blowfish Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300694/how-to-loop-over-blowfish-crypto)

Comment: I think the references you are looking for are [GCM Mode](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/GCM_Mode), [AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter) and [AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `iv.size()` rather than `sizeof(iv)` when you try to set `d2.SetKeyWithIV`, just like what you have done to `e.SetKeyWithIV`. 
Because in this program, the value of `iv.size()` is 16, but `sizeof(iv)` is 24. Then it will work.

```
GCM< AES >::Decryption d2;
d2.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, iv.size()); //here was a misuse of sizeof(iv)

StringSource fs2(efilename, true,
        new AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter( d2,
                new FileSink (rfilename.c_str()),
                AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION));
```

The code which has passed my test is as above.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So, I updated my answer after debugging on the MAC. When I tried to build the libcrypto, I referred to one of your former answer about [Installing Crypto++ 5.6.2 on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728659/installing-crypto-5-6-2-on-mac-os-x). Thanks.

Comment: Good catch, Eric. I fixed the wiki so it no longer says `decryptor.SetKeyWithIV(...);`. Now it calls it like above to avoid copy/paste mistakes.

Comment: I guess  the mistake was in the implementation of the algorithm after all